# Get permalink of post that an attachment is linked to

Tags: posts

How do I get the permalink of a post that an attachment image is attached to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent); ?>">Attachment parent</a>
```